# Sumar 2 números el mínimo de veces posible hasta N Java

Tags: java

Apenas llevo tiempo programando y no consigo sacar esto. Creo que el razonamiento está bien pero no consigo plasmarlo en código.

Quiero hacer un ejemplo donde tenga que sumar 2 números el mínimo de veces necesarias hasta llegar a N, por ejemplo:

N=10; num1=2; num2=4;

El resultado más óptimo sería: 4+4+2

Resultados NO óptimos: 2+2+2+2+2, 4+2+2+2, 2+4+2+2, etc.

Mi lógica es la siguiente:

- Crear una función que detecte cuál es el mayor de los 2 números.
- Restar el número mayor al N siempre y cuando el resto sea divisible entre num1 o num2, o por el contrario restar el menor.
- Cuando el resto de un resultado distinto de 0, mostrar la cantidad óptima de num1 y num2, y mostrar el número que me queda de resto.

Solo consigo hacerlo con 1 numero, no con los 2.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 3;
    int num2 = 2;
    int objetivo = 10;

    int numMayor;
    int numMenor;
    int conta1 = 0;
    int conta2 = 0;

    if (num1 > num2) {
        numMayor = num1;
        numMenor = num2;
    } else {
        numMayor = num2;
        numMenor = num1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= objetivo; i++) {
        if(objetivo - numMayor != 0) {
            objetivo = objetivo - numMayor;
            conta1++;
        }

        if(objetivo - numMenor !=0 ) {
            objetivo = objetivo - numMenor;
            conta2++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("NumMayor: "+conta1 + "NumMenor: "+conta2 + ": " + objetivo);
}
```

Comment: Quizá deberías comprobar si `(objetivo - num es >= 0)`, porque `10 - (4+4+4) != 0` pero nos hemos pasado. Por otro lado, yo usaría un bucle while, no un for

Comment: Puedes resolverlo con divisiones y sin bucles. Si lo haces así, cuando le pongas un número muy grande se va a "morir" el procesador.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor idea para enfrentar este problema es partir del "Mejor Escenario" que ocurre cuando el objetivo es divisible por el `numMayor`. En el mejor de los casos, la respuesta sería directamente `contadorMax = objetivo / numMayor` y `contadorMin = 0`. Nota el mejor acercamiento SIEMPRE se logra cuando usamos la **cantidad máxima de números mayores**, de lo contrario, tendremos más términos de los que se necesitan en realidad.

La idea es la siguiente:

- Probar siempre si podemos alcanzar el **número objetivo** con la cantidad máxima de números mayores `objetivo / numMayor;` y cubriendo el `resto` (en caso de existir) con cierta cantidad de números menores.
- Si el **número mayor** es completamente divisible entre el objetivo o bien el resto puede cubrirse con el **número menor**, entonces hemos encontrado el mejor caso.
- De lo contrario, quitamos un número mayor de la suma y checamos si esta vez, el número menor puede cubrir ese resto.

Puede que no sea la implementación más óptima, pero funciona bastante bien. Ten en cuenta que num1 y num2 deben ser mayores que cero. En caso de no poderse cubrir el objetivo con sumas, los contadores quedarán en cero:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = 102;
        int num2 = 2;
        int objetivo = 100;

        int numMayor = Math.max( num1, num2 );
        int numMenor = Math.min( num1, num2 );
        int contadorMax = 0;
        int contadorMin = 0;

        int div = objetivo / numMayor;
        while (div >= 0) {
            int resto = objetivo - (numMayor * div);
            if (resto >= 0 && resto % numMenor == 0) {
                contadorMax =  div;
                contadorMin = resto / numMenor;
                break;
            }
            div--;
        }

        System.out.println( "Contador de Máximo: " + contadorMax + " Contador de Mínimo: " + contadorMin );
    }
}
```